# How to enable $levels in oData .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I have developed an oData server with .Net core 3.1.

Asp.net in its older versions support `$levels` for example check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/max-expansion-depth-in-enable-query-attribute).

In my server I can expand my queries until 2 levels. It means a URL like the following:

```
https://localhost:44375/odata.svc/Patients?$expand=PatientForms($expand=Form)
```

works in my server and I can see the expanded results. Now if I try to perform it with `$levels`:

```
https://localhost:44375/odata.svc/Patients?$expand=PatientForms($levels=2)
```

then I will get the following error:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The $level option on navigation property 'PatientForms' is not allowed, because the related entity type 'mjzsoft.Models.PatientForm' could not be cast to source entity type 'mjzsoft.Models.Patient'.

The controllers for `Patient` and `PatientForm` and `Form` are as follows, however as they have exactly same structure with different model names, therefore, I just reflected one of them here:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Patients")]
    public class PatientsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly XxxDbContext xxxDbContext;
        public PatientsController(XxxDbContext xxxDbContext)
                => this.xxxDbContext = xxxDbContext;
        
        [ODataRoute]
        [EnableQuery]
        //[PagingValidatorQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(this.xxxDbContext.Patients);
        }

        [ODataRoute("{id}")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] ulong id)
        {
            return Ok(this.xxxDbContext.Patients.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id));
        }

    }
```

In the database each `Patient` can have several `Form`. Hence, as this is an M to N relationship we have `PatientForms` in between.

Comment: Each Patient can have several Form => It might be a 1 to N relationship.

Comment: And each Form can assign to different patients. => it is M to N!

Comment: Hi, @Mahdi J.Ansari , did this answer solved you question? If so, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: @MichelleWang Actually not! Otherwise I would mark it already! This question is still open! I will try it again and let you know.

Comment: Hi,@Mahdi J.Ansari, $levels only can expand same object, That's why you get error here.

Comment: Comment has sub comment and the sub comment has its sub comment....  Here you can use $levels to decide how many levels do you expand.

Comment: OK. Now got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The $level option on
> navigation property 'PatientForms' is not allowed, because the related
> entity type 'mjzsoft.Models.PatientForm' could not be cast to source
> entity type 'mjzsoft.Models.Patient'.

I met this problem with your codes.
From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/max-expansion-depth-in-enable-query-attribute) you post, it said `$levels` only used to expand **same object**.

```
$expand=Manager($levels=max) will be the same as $expand=Manager($expand=Manager)   
$expand=Manager($levels=3) will be the same as $expand=Manager($expand=Manager($expand=Manager))
```

As for your case, you need `$expand=PatientForms($expand=Paitent)`
`$expand=PatientForms($levels=2)` will expect to expand `PatientForms` but `Paitent` and the cast error showed up.

Here are test results of using `$levels` below.

> Comments => $expand once

[image]

> `Comments => $expand twice`  is same as  `Comments => $levels=2`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this ($levels) doesn't work on Dataverse 9.2 (although it says it supports OData 4.0). Any idea why?